# How to make a static class update its own variables constantly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have a user control that displays information from the database. This user control has to update these information constantly(let's say every 5 seconds). A few instances of this user control is generated programmatically during run time in a single page. In the code behind of this user control I added a code that sends a query to the database to get the needed information (which means every single instance of the user control is doing this). But this seems to slow down the processing of queries so I am making a static class that will do the querying and store the information in its variables and let the instances of my user control access those variables. Now I need this static class to do queries every 5 seconds to update its variables. I tried using a new thread to do this but the variables don't seem to be updated since I always get a NullReferenceException whenever I access them from a different class.

Here's my static class:

```
public static class SessionManager
{
    public static volatile List<int> activeSessionsPCIDs;
    public static volatile List<int> sessionsThatChangedStatus;
    public static volatile List<SessionObject> allSessions;

    public static void Initialize() {
        Thread t = new Thread(SetProperties);
        t.Start();
    }

    public static void SetProperties() {
        SessionDataAccess sd = new SessionDataAccess();
        while (true) {
            allSessions = sd.GetAllSessions();
            activeSessionsPCIDs = new List<int>();
            sessionsThatChangedStatus = new List<int>();
            foreach (SessionObject session in allSessions) {
                if (session.status == 1) { //if session is active
                    activeSessionsPCIDs.Add(session.pcid);
                }
                if (session.status != session.prevStat) { //if current status doesn't match the previous status
                    sessionsThatChangedStatus.Add(session.pcid);
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
```

And this is how I am trying to access the variables in my static class:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SessionManager.Initialize();
        loadSessions();
    }

    private void loadSessions()
    { // refresh the current_sessions table
        List<int> pcIds = pcl.GetPCIds(); //get the ids of all computers
        foreach (SessionObject s in SessionManager.allSessions)
        {
            SessionInfo sesInf = (SessionInfo)LoadControl("~/UserControls/SessionInfo.ascx");
            sesInf.session = s;
            pnlMonitoring.Controls.Add(sesInf);
        } 
    }
```

Any help, please? Thanks

Comment: mmm... i suspect that as soon as the initialize function completes, thread t gets killed because t is scoped to the function.  you probably want something like the singleton pattern.

Comment: I guess noone here noticed that you are running a growing number of background threads - with each page load you call `Initialize` and that starts up a new thread (and don't tell me you intend to tell all your users to never refresh the page, or to not use the app if another user is using it until IIS recycles everything). You end up with a clutter of threads and you have no mutexes / monitors / locks. I'm not sure `volatile` saves you from the situation when threads other than the one assigning values to the static fields do not observe a changed value and experience `null` - check my edit

Answer (score 3):

**Multiple threads problem**

You have one thread that gets created for each and every call to `SessionManager.Initialize`.

That happens more than once in the lifetime of the process.
IIS recycles your app at some point, after a period of time should you have absolutely no requests.
Until that happens, all your created threads continue to run.

After the first `PageLoad` you will have one thread which updates stuff every 5 seconds.

If you refresh the page again you'll have two threads, possibly with different offsets in time but each of which, doing the same thing at 5 second intervals.

You should **atomically** check to see if your background thread is started already. You need at least an extra **bool** static field and a **object** static field which you should use like a `Monitor` (using the `lock` keyword).

You should also stop relying on volatile and simply using `lock` to make sure that other threads "observe" updated values for your static `List<..>` fields.

It may be the case that the other threads don't observe a change field and thusly, for them, the field is still `null` - therefore you get the `NullReferenceException`.

**About volatile**

Using `volatile` is bad, at least in .NET. There is a 90% chance that you think you know what it is doing and it's not true and there's a 99% chance that you feel relief because you used `volatile` and you aren't checking for other multitasking hazards the way you should.

**RX to the rescue**

I strongly suggest you take a look at this wonderful thing called [Reactive Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx).

Believe me, a couple of days' research combined with the fact that you're in a perfect position to use RX will pay of, not just now but in the future as well.

You get to keep your static class, but instead of materialised values that get stored within that class you create *pipes* that carry information. The information flows when you want it to flow. You get to have *subscribers* to those pipes. The number of subscribers does not affect the overall performance of your app.

Your app will be more scalable, and more robust.

Good luck!

Comment: I agree RX & MEF are awesome framework and help have a more flexible application. But I guess for this approach, RX makes the code more complicated and using job to fetch data from DB at specific time frame solve the problem (that's just my idea)

Comment: @Peyman - Don't get me wrong - I haven't provided code, you have and it is appreciated. My idea includes your `Task.Factory.StartNew` also. What I'm proposing is just a modern distribution system for flowing events - I'm not actually saying anything about the Job / Scheduler.

Comment: Ok @Eduard , sorry I thought you suggest him to use RX as a solution

Comment: @Peyman Thanks for your suggestion. I just have a question though. I intended to create a thread everytime the page loads because I thought that the previous threads will be destroyed everytime the page posts back. Isn't that what's happening? I'm sorry, I don't really have that much knowledge about multi-threading

Comment: @Rian as I know it depends on your thread scope, but if you don't want to care about Threading and manage it you can use [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/)

Comment: I'm sorry. That last comment was intended for @Eduard Dumitru. My bad.

Comment: definitely a good use case for Rx.  I'd say that its a bit more complicated to "wire-up" than SignalR, but it has its advantages.

Answer (score 2):

There are few solution for this approach:
One of them is:

It's better in Global.asax in Application_start or Session_Start (depends on your case) create Thread to call your method:

Use below code :

```
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    while(true)
    {
      SessionManager.SetProperties();
      Task.Delay(5);
    }
});
```

Second solution is using Job Scheduler for ASP.NET (that's my ideal solution).
for more info you can check this link [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

and third solution is rewrite your static class as follow:

```
public static class SessionManager
{
 public static volatile List<int> activeSessionsPCIDs;
 public static volatile List<int> sessionsThatChangedStatus;
 public static volatile List<SessionObject> allSessions;

 static SessionManager()
 {
   Initialize();
 }

public static void Initialize() {
    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
       while(true)
       {
         SetProperties();
         Task.Delay(5);
       }
     });
}

public static void SetProperties() {
    SessionDataAccess sd = new SessionDataAccess();
    while (true) {
        allSessions = sd.GetAllSessions();
        activeSessionsPCIDs = new List<int>();
        sessionsThatChangedStatus = new List<int>();
        foreach (SessionObject session in allSessions) {
            if (session.status == 1) { //if session is active
                activeSessionsPCIDs.Add(session.pcid);
            }
            if (session.status != session.prevStat) { //if current status doesn't match the previous status
                sessionsThatChangedStatus.Add(session.pcid);
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will definitely try this and mark your answer accordingly. Sorry for the mistake in the above. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that is a change in approach, but I kept the solution in Web Forms, to make it more directly applicable to your use case.

SignalR is a technology that enables real-time, two way communication between server and clients (browsers), which can replace your static session data class.  Below, I have implemented a simple example to demonstrate the concept.

As a sample, create a new ASP.NET Web Forms application and add the SignalR package from nuget.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
```

You will need to add a new `Owin Startup class` and add these 2 lines:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
```

... and within the method

```
app.MapSignalR();
```

Add some UI elements to `Default.aspx`:

```
 <div class="jumbotron">

    <H3 class="MyName">Loading...</H3>

    <p class="stats">

    </p>

</div>
```

Add the following JavaScript to the `Site.Master`.  This code references signalr, and implement client-side event handlers and initiates contact with the signalr hub from the browser.  here's the code:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
<script >
    var hub = $.connection.sessiondata;
    hub.client.someOneJoined = function (name) {
        var current = $(".stats").text();
        current = current + '\nuser ' + name + ' joined.';
        $(".stats").text(current);
    };
    hub.client.myNameIs = function (name) {
        $(".MyName").text("Your user id: " + name);
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () { });
</script>
```

Finally, add a `SignalR Hub` to the solution and use this code for the `SessionDataHub` implementation:

```
[HubName("sessiondata")]
public class SessionDataHub : Hub
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> sessions = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public SessionDataHub()
    {
        sessions.CollectionChanged += sessions_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void sessions_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            Clients.All.someOneJoined(e.NewItems.Cast<string>().First());
        }
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var youAre = Context.ConnectionId;
            Clients.Caller.myNameIs(youAre);
            sessions.Add(youAre);
        });
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        // TODO: implement this as well. 
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
}
```

For more information about SignalR, go to http://asp.net/signalr

Link to source code: https://lsscloud.blob.core.windows.net/downloads/WebApplication1.zip

Comment: That looks swell. This will become my cheatsheet for SignalR from now on :) even though I use MVC :)

Comment: works with MVC with a very similar code base (substitute Site.Master for _Layout.cshtml, etc)

Comment: i've used SignalR in the past but not for a while and .. I didn't know they made these wonderful `dynamic` expando transparent proxy thingies (I'm guessing that is what `Clients.All.someoneJoined` on the server side). It looks marvelous :). I don't think SignalR had that from the get go

Comment: @GlennFerrie Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. Will definitely try it and will mark you answer accordingly.